# line height not affecting anything in my app

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a form like below in my rails app

```
<p class='field'>
    <div class = "form-group">
      <div class = "col-sm-3 mobile-label" >
       <%= form.label :loyalty%>
       <%=image_tag "qun1.png" ,:style=>"width: 15px; display:inline-block", 'data-toggle'=>"modal", 'data-target'=>"#myModal1"  %>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-9">
      <%= form.text_field :coupon_code, :class => 'form-control col-sm-9' %>
     <%= button_tag "Apply", class: 'btn btn-lg btn-success primary payment-code col-sm-3 ',id: 'apcode' %>
    </div>
    </div>
</p>

<p class='fild>
  <div class = "form-group">
    <div class = "col-sm-3 mobile-label" >
     <%= form.label :coupon_code %>
    </div>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
     <%= form.text_field :coupon_code, :class => 'form-control col-sm-9 ' %>
     <%= button_tag "Apply", class: 'btn btn-lg btn-success primary payment-code col-sm-3 ',id: 'apcode' %>  
   </div>
 </div>
</p>
```

The result which I am getting is, there are no gap between the label.textfield and button element in both the form groups.

When I am giving `line-height:30px;` to my label, It completely breaks. Anything less than that is not affecting anything.

Here's the somewhat similar [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m40ts1rr/)

Please help.

Comment: show the generated HTML instead

Comment: [check](https://jsfiddle.net/m40ts1rr/) this @dippas

Answer (score 2):

```
style="line-height:30px";
```

Put this code in the class field and try if your error is sorted out or not.

Comment: This really didn't work for me. When I am giving `margin-bottom:50px;` this works for me but then when I have another form group, then the 2nd and 3rd form groups are coming over each other..

Comment: Try display:inline-block; once. see what happens.